# Unable to Download file using flask with actual name

Tags: python, flask, download, sendfile

I am trying to download the file using flask. my code is as follows

```
@app.route('/Download')
def Down():
    rpm = request.args.get('rpm')
    root = '/home/rpmbuild/RPMS/'
    return send_from_directory(root,rpm)
```

The name of the file is passed in the url. when i hit the url, I am able to download the file but the name of the file in always `Download`. i need it to be actual name of the file. I have also tried `send_file()` but it is also downloading it with the name `Download`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "options" of [`send_from_directory`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory) are the same as [`sendfile`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file):

```
flask.send_file(filename_or_fp, mimetype=None, as_attachment=False,
                attachment_filename=None, add_etags=True,
                cache_timeout=None, conditional=False,
                last_modified=None)
```

So you should call it with:

```
@app.route('/Download')
def Down():
    rpm = request.args.get('rpm')
    root = '/home/rpmbuild/RPMS/'
    return send_from_directory(root,rpm,attachment_filename='foo.ext')
```

Where you of course substitute `'foo.ext'` by the name you want to give the file. You probably also want to set the `as_attachment` parameter to `True`.

In case you want the **same name**, you can use `os.path.basename(..)` for that:

```
import os

@app.route('/Download')
def Down():
    rpm = request.args.get('rpm')
    root = '/home/rpmbuild/RPMS/'
    return send_from_directory(root,rpm,as_attachment=True,
                               attachment_filename=os.path.basename(rpm))
```